# .Net Winforms navigation issue

Tags: c#, winforms, navigation

I am facing a problem with a Winforms app. If I scroll down and then minimize the app and then maximize it, navigation goes to the top of the page. I need to fix this so that people using this app dont have to find where they were before minimizing the app.

Any help or thoughts would be great.

Comment: What you mean by navigation? The focus of the control?

Answer (score 1):

You're not really giving enough information but assuming that you've got a `Panel` (or another control that inherits from `ScrollableControl`) on your form that contains all the other controls and that is the control that the user has scrolled in you could probably do the following:

Handle the `Resize` event and store `panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value` somewhere when it's minimized and when it's maximized the `Resize` event will be called again and you could then set `panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value` to the stored value.

Handling the `Resize` event isn't a perfect way to catch minimize and maximize but it would probably work well enough since otherwise it would get a bit more difficult.